# JS regex to match a word in the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a data-prototype that renders a form. The inputs are rendered as :

```
<input type="text" id="loan_charges_1_date" name="loan[charges][1][date]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="loan_charges_1_duration" name="loan[charges][1][duration]" class="form-control">
```

...
next render :

```
<input type="text" id="loan_charges_2_date" name="loan[charges][2][date]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="loan_charges_2_duration" name="loan[charges][2][duration]" class="form-control">
```

I want to write a JS script to work with dates. So, basically I need a way to catch a input by `id` that ends with `_date` or simply `date`. I think here I need a regular expresion that match `_date` or `date` in a string, preferable at the end of that string.
Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to match date inside the id attribute with `match()`.

```js
var bodyText =  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
var ids = bodyText.match(/id="(.*date)"/g);
var idArray = ids.map(x => x = x.split('\"')[1]);
console.log(idArray);

idArray.forEach( x => document.getElementById(x).value = Date());
```

```html
<input type="text" id="loan_charges_1_date" name="loan[charges][1][date]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="loan_charges_1_duration" name="loan[charges][1][duration]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="loan_charges_2_date" name="loan[charges][2][date]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="loan_charges_2_duration" name="loan[charges][2][duration]" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Sorry, need some change, now it match my global form `<input id = "loan_date"` as well :/ , so need to change the regex to match `loan_charges_i_date` where `i` is an integer.

So, I have now an `idArray`. My goal from the beginning was to select value of the input with id that ends with `_date_`. To take this value, in other input with id that ends with `_duration` to take this value as well, and add this amount of `months` to date.value and output it in a hint paragraph. Can you help me a little bit more? Thank you!

Comment: Just modify the regex to `/id="(.*_date_)"/g`. You can modify the bodyText to point to your div which contains all your form elements with `date` id.

Comment: I changed the bodyText, so it works. 
I commented  `idArray.forEach( x => document.getElementById(x).value = Date());` as well.
So, when I press `+` it adds me a new form based on data-prototype.
So, I have a form with 2 clear inputs : date and duration.
To make calculations on data, I need that immediately when I type a date value in date input, to take this value. (How can i do it?) and after that to make some calculation and output the new value in a paragraph

Comment: Search for `onkeyup` event in javascript. It will help you to make calculation when you fill the textbox.

Comment: I know about `onkeyup` event, but how can I apply it on a specific input? 
I mean... when I press a `+` button it renders me a new form with this 2 inputs. I need when I introduce `date` at input, the hint paragraph to appears next to this input, in the same row...

Comment: To display hint, you can use `tooltip`. You can bind those event with some pre written function add it as part of your `d.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'alert(\'hello\');');`

Comment: Hi again.  So, i binded an function to each idArray. (this is all about the date input). Now, to make my function working, I need to do same with duration. So, I copy-pasted and edited a little bit the code, to make it done for duration inputs as well. So, now I have 2 different arrays. I renamed them to make them a little bit clear :
dateIdArray and durationIdArray. 
They both have data like :   dateIdArray = loan_charge_1_date, loan_charge_2_date.
durationArrray = loan_charge_1_duration, loan_charge_2_duration.
To make my calculator-function working, I need to run the function with

Comment: 2 arguments.. function endingDateCalculator(valueOfDate, valueOfDuration) {}
How can from this 2 array to make one, that have pair-values  like  loan_charge_1_date and loan_charge_1_duration together,  loan_charge_2_date and loan_charge_2_duration together ... and to this pairs run function with 2 parameters?
Thank you.

Comment: Now my script looks like :
var bodyText =  document.getElementsByClassName('panel-group')[0].innerHTML;
var durationIds = bodyText.match(/id="(.*duration)"/g);
var durationIdArray = durationIds.map(x => x = x.split('\"')[1]);

var dateIds = bodyText.match(/id="(.*date)"/g);
var dateIdArray = dateIds.map(x => x = x.split('\"')[1]);
dateIdArray.forEach( x => document.getElementById(x).setAttribute('onkeyup', 'endingDateCalculator(this.value);'));

function endingDateCalculator(valueOfDate, valueOfDuration) {
    alert(valueOfInput + "huhu");
}

Comment: You can use simple for loop with and access array element by its index and do your calculation. In case you have your input fields are immediate siblings, you can use TagNames to access each of them by index.

Answer (score -1):

The regex is `/_date$/`

`/_date$/.test('sample_date')
true
/_date$/.test('date_sample')
false`

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for stupid question... how can I use this regex to "getElementById" ?